# sql + php - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array why

Tags: php, sql

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","root","photoshare");
$query = "SELECT ID,nickname,photoLikes FROM tbl_photo";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$query_dislike = "SELECT nickname, idGivenLike FROM tbl_check_like";
$resultDislike = mysqli_query($con,$query_dislike);
$photoIDdislike;
$photoID;
while($photoID = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result) || $photoIDdislike = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDislike)   )
{
//checks if both of results
if($result["ID"] != $resultDislike["idGivenLike"])
{
echo "true";
}
}
?>
```

When I run it it's says that the next line

```
if($result["ID"] != $resultDislike["idGivenLike"])
```

With h Fatal error:  `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array`

why it's doesnt work and how may i fix it?

Comment: Replace `$resultDislike` with `$photoIDdislike` in your `if`-block

Comment: `$result["ID"]` should be `$photoID["ID"]` and `$resultDislik["idGivenLike"]` should be `$photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"]` in your loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($result["ID"] != $resultDislike["idGivenLike"])
```

Should be:

```
if($photoID["ID"] != $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"])
```

`$resultDislike/$result` is your MySQL resource, `$photoID/$photoIDdislike` is the fetched row (array).

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$photoID["ID"] != $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"]
// In script 
if($photoID["ID"] != $photoIDdislike["idGivenLike"])
{
   echo "true";
}
```